# '$ is not defined' in code following jQuery include

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the familiar '$ is not defined' error in my JavaScript for the following line in one of my javascript files...

```
$(document).ready(function() { … }
```

Normally this is because I've forgotten to include jQuery, but not this time! I have included it, and it is the first include in the page. This error happens in included JavaScript files, and also in any code within  tags, all of which come **after** the jQuery include. It also doesn't happen all the time, maybe half the time when I refresh the page.

I've also used jQuery quite a lot and never seen this before, so I am quite confused.

Edit:
Looking at the Net tab in Firebug, jQuery is being requested and I get a 200 response but nothing is sent back in the response body. If I open the file directly in a new tab or whatever, I get an empty document. Firefox seems to think the file is cached but the data size is 0. Cache control is 'no-cache'. Confused.

Edit 2:
Opened jQuery file in VisualStudio, saved jQuery file with no modifications, everything works perfectly now. Still totally confused.

Comment: Well, @toiletseat, could we see the `<head>` or whatever?

Comment: how are you loading jquery, from local or google?

Comment: What about a link to your page? Or should we imagine what your code looks like?

Comment: How `'$ is not defined'` can be _familiar_? You never learn from your mistakes?

Comment: @ClemDesm, its familiar in the sense it comes up a lot on StackOverflow, I've not caused it myself in a long time

Comment: You probably just have a typo in your src reference.  Maybe you are missing the closing `</script>` tag?

Comment: @InrBob, we are using a local copy of jQuery

Comment: @Pointy, the `<head>` is pretty cluttered and untidy as it is generated by our CMS, but there's nothing out of the ordinary in it. I've been using jQuery for >2 years so I'm pretty confident with it, but this has me stumped!

Comment: @shanabus, no typo, the error is intermittent between page loads and even refreshes of the same page. I think our CMS is to blame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ***sure*** that jQuery is actually being loaded into the browser? It sounds like it really isn't.  You should use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check all the http requests to see if it is actually being downloaded.

Here's a screenshot of how you can check this using Firebug.
[image]

Comment: So the file was being requested and returned, but IIS was *sometimes* returning an empty file, causing the error. Opening the file in VisualStudio and saving it has inexplicably fixed the problem. Something to do with caching and Windows timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Wordpress or some sort of CMS? If so, their version of jQuery may have of code at the end which calls `jQuery.noConflict()`. You can read about this method here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

This means that whenever you want to use the `$` function, you need to use `jQuery` instead.

#### For example...

Instead of

```
$("p").addClass("awesome");
```

You would do

```
jQuery("p").addClass("awesome").
```

Comment: Yep, we are using a CMS, I was wondering if this was the culprit, but it isn't the problem you mention exactly. I think it **is** to blame though...

Comment: Wow, well I am stumped then. Good luck.